# why sqlite behave like this

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add new column my books table but showing error:- is i am doing something wrong.

**Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table books already exists**

above error

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE books (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title TEXT ,author TEXT,isbn TEXT,city TEXT );");


            Log.v("onCreate-------","called onCreate"); 

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            android.util.Log.w("books",
            "Upgrading database, which will destroy all old data");
            //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE books ADD COLUMN city2 TEXT");

            onCreate(db);
            Log.v("onUpgrade-------","called onUpgrade with alter"); 
        }
```

Comment: if it Showing Error To you then show error also here To predict about the root cause

Comment: see very first line coused by :-

Comment: What is error? Can you post your logcat's logs?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're calling `onCreate` from `onUpgrade`? I this you're getting `Table books already exists` or something-like-that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onCreate(db);
Log.v("onUpgrade-------","called onUpgrade with alter");
```

No need to call onCreate again here. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the create query to -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following to check if Database already exists or not ?
May be following helps you.

```
public static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.test.appname/databases/";
public static final String DB_NAME = "databasename.db";
public boolean checkDBExists()
{
    try 
    {
        File file = new File(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);
        if(file.exists())
        {
          // do nothing
        }
        else
        {
         db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE books (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title TEXT ,author TEXT,isbn TEXT,city TEXT );");
        }
   }
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return false;
   }
}
```